# Why is the syntax of java generics the way it is

Tags: java, generics

In the java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), an example of the java generics is like this.

```
/**
 * Generic version of the Box class.
 * @param <T> the type of the value being boxed
 */
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

Why is the `<T>` right after `Box`. I know that `T` stands for the Type the user will use.
But if you look at the rest of the syntax, `T` always comes first.

For example in `private T  t;` T comes before t.

In the methods `get()` and `set(T t)`, we again see that `T` comes before the method name and not after the name of the object or method we are creating.

It is my understanding that a class such as Box is also an Object, so why don't we write:

```
public class T Box { //... }
```

Or, alternatively,

```
public <T> class Box { //... }
```

I would like to know this because it confuses me. Whenever I am writing a generic method, I have to go back to existing code to see which comes first so maybe if I knew why one has to come first and why the other has to come last I will not have to go back to my already existing code and use it as a reference.

Comment: Well, those are *type arguments*. Arguments never come first. For instance, a method's name comes first, then the possible arguments. By the way, shouldn't be too hard to remember, I think you get used to it pretty quickly.

Comment: I think this got inherited from C++ templating, where the template is after the class name. I think they made this choice as the language grammar is easier to write if you have it on the right side instead of the left. The other reason is readability. You should read it like Box for T, and not the type for Box.

Comment: in the field and method declaration, the T stands for some type, that will be replaced at runtime by some concrete class (e.g. String, Socket, Integer) and follows the syntax of non-generic fields/methods. But in the class definition of Box, it defines that class to be generic, expecting you declare the T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is called a *type parameter*, and it is very similar to a method parameter. In the description below, the word "class" also covers "interface", but using the common word "type" would be confusing.

You declare a method with a *formal parameter* like this:

```
void foo(Animal a)
```

You declare a generic class with a *type parameter* like this:

```
class Foo<A extends Animal>
```

Of course `a` is a value, a reference to an Animal instance, while `A` is a type, a compiler reference to a class.

`a` is called a *parameter variable*, and `A` is called a *type variable*.

You call the method like this:

```
foo(a)
```

You use the generic class like this:

```
Foo<Dog>
```

`a` is the method *argument* (sometimes called the *actual parameter*), and `Dog` is the generic *type argument*.

It is that similarity to method parameters that make the placement of generic type parameter intuitive to use, at least once you realize the similarity.

---

The placement of generic method type parameters is less intuitive, until you recognize that the type parameter should be defined before it's used, and the first possible use is the return type, so the type parameters are declared right before that:

```
<A extends Animal> A foo(A a)
```

Less obvious is on the method call, if the compiler cannot infer the type argument:

```
myobj.<Dog>foo(mydog)
```

But that's where they decided to put it, probably for code parsing reasons.

Comment: Bravo! I give you a billion votes. There is a spelling error in the last line. But I could not edit this beautiful answer. Thanks! @MatTimmermans had not explained the part about generic methods

Answer (score 1):

> I know that T stands for the Type the user will use.

That's correct.  Keep reminding yourself of that.

> For example in `private T  t;` T comes before t.

That's because T is the type.  If it were an Integer, the line would look like `private Integer t;` and if it were a Boolean, then it would look like `private Boolean t;`.  That's simply the syntax of Java:  modifiers, then the type, then the variable name being declared.

In a generic, `T` (or whatever placeholder you want to use) is the placeholder for the type, inside that class, so you put a `T` instead of Integer or Boolean or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

`Box<T>` is a type with parameter `T` in the same way that `void box(int t)` is method with parameter `t`.  The angle brackets indicate type parameters, while the round parentheses indicate method parameters.

The `T` is a parameter of the class `Box` and nothing else, which is why it doesn't appear in angle brackets anywhere else.

The generic method syntax: `<T> void box(T t);` is a little harder to understand.  `box` is not a type, so it doesn't take type parameters, and that's why the `<T>` doesn't come after `box`.  There is no type in that declaration to attach it to.  It probably goes before the method declaration so that it doesn't confuse the meaning of the rest of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

T is like a variable for a class/type.
Just replace all the Ts in your question with e.g. String or Integer etc. and you get regular Java Syntax.

E.g. private T foo(T t) becomes private String foo(String t)...